# How to manage QGIS styles saved in Spatialite

Tags: qgis, style, spatialite

At QGIS 2.14 the style files we have saved in our Spatialite database do not show the labels anymore.

Luckily I have the Layer Definition Files saved that still display the labels, but in trying to re-save (overwrite) the style to the Spatialite database (using the same name), I get the following:

[image]

While I'm able to save with a new name, how can I remove the old styles so I don't end up with too many old styles?

**EDIT:** Turns out the style saved for 2.14 doesn't show the labels either, so maybe this is a bigger issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a plugin (!) called **Qspatialite**

There is a SQL interface to the styles in your Spatialite database, and you can run SQL commands to view, delete, and rename your styles:

[image]

[image]

Delete an old style:

[image]